# What are some techniques to improve generalization for subsets with varied distributions?

Tags: distributions, model, binary-data

Suppose I have a binary classification problem in which I have a set comprising subjects, and each subject contributes with a varied number of positive and negative samples to the whole set. The distribution of negative and positive samples per-subject varies a lot, with some having no positive samples at all, while others have up to 40%/60% ratio of +1/-1.

When splitting this set in training, validation, and testing sets, I made sure to do it as balanced as possible, such that training, validation, and testing all have a similar distribution of subjects with unbalanced and balanced number of +1/-1 samples.

Training my model uses all samples from all subjects in the training set, and so does validation for selecting the best model. However, when I test the model, it is interesting for me to look at each subject of the testing set individually, as if it were a single test set, and then average my performance among all subjects in the test set. As expected, this presents a challenge because the whole set of samples in the training set might have a very different distribution from individual subjects in the testing sets.

So my question is: what kinds of techniques I can employ to help generalize my model to individual subjects in the test set?